# Unable to build Cordova Android on Mac

Tags: android, ios, xcode, macos, cordova

```
Krishnas-MacBook-Air:trialapp krishnalahoti$ cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/krishnalahoti/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
Error: spawn EACCES
```

While running the command for "cordova build android" i am getting the following error and unable to figure out the solution to make a successful cordova android build on ios
[image: Link to the terminal image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add execute permissions to the Gradle demon as it only has `rw-r--r` by default.

Assuming you have Android Studio installed, you can do this by running the below command

```
$ chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/bin/gradle-<VERSION HERE>/bin/gradle
```